# Bootloader not working

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

With not apperant reason when I booted my computed today I got to a Grub command line screen.

As far as I read it seems that the grub might been defected. I've downloaded the Ubuntu live CD and ran the Boot Repair program, at the end I've got `Boot successfully repaired.` message with a [paste](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5943350/).
After rebooting I still don't get my boot loader and unable to get into my Ubuntu installation.

I have not backed up files there which I can't figure how to backup, could yo guys assist me getting back into my Ubuntu installation or at least provide a way I could get files located under my user home folder?

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

As for fixing GRUB, I'll leave that someone more GRUB-savvy. I've had a similar problem as you, but when I repaired from the Live CD, it *actually* fixed my problem.

Recovering your data shouldn't be too difficult. The general process is as follows:
 
1. Boot into Live CD
 2. Find your storage device
 3. Mount your storage device
 4. Mount your recovery storage device
 5. Copy necessary files across

**1. Boot into Live CD**

I won't bore you with the steps for doing 1 (since you've already done it).

**2. Find your storage device**

Depending on how your hard drive is partitioned, it might be a bit tricky to determine which partition is the one you need. My personal preference is to run:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null
```

That should give you an output that has a number of entries that look like:
/dev/sdxX: LABEL="LABEL_NAME" UUID="UUID_HERE" TYPE="FILETYPE"

You're interested in finding the correct drive from information like the filetype and label name. Once you've correctly identified the correct drive/partition, then you want to take a note of x and X (from /dev/sdxX). You'll need that bit to mount your drive.

**3. Mount your storage device**

Before you mount the drive, you need to create a folder to actually mount to. I suggest you create one in your home folder, such as (~/my_original_drive).

Once you've created that, you will want to run a command that is similar to the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdxX ~/my_original_drive
```

Replacing x and X from the letter and number derived from the previous section.

From here, you should be able to access your data from the 'my_orignal_drive' folder. Have a look around in there and make sure everything is there as you expected.

**4. Mount your recovery storage device**

To be honest, you shouldn't need to do much here if you're plugging in a USB stick (the newer versions of Ubuntu Live CD should mount these automagically). If it doesn't, follow the same steps above, but for your back-up device. It'll have a different /dev/sdxX and you'll need to create another folder to mount to.

If the backup drive *does* mount automagically, it'll be located somewhere under /media/

**5. Copy necessary files across**

Once you've correctly mounted both your backup and source drives, it should just be a matter of copying and pasting!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, as for backup it seems I'm all set, So I can just format and install Ubuntu on a clean hard drive.
Though I'll wait bit longer for someone who might be able to provide a way to fix grub.